# Can low RAM and large OBB file size be an issue?

Tags: split, unity-game-engine, apk, ram, expansion

Here are the important details of my application :

APK size : 9mb
OBB size : 350mb

The game runs on all devices except :

Samsung Galaxy ace Plus
Google nexus S

Both have 512 MB RAM
Both have ARMv7 processors

The crash happens here:

WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(uri , 0);
//the return statement never executes
yield return www;

Any idea how low RAM could affect the game?

Note : Game is made in Unity 3D 4.2.0

Comment: Oh yes, that could very well be the cause. A lot of memory is required to unpack large files. And you'll get no warning of you running out.

Comment: What are my options, other than reducing the size? .. Is there any other way to implement reading the files without unpacking in Unity?

Comment: You could opt for Asset Bundles so you can split your assets into multiple packages. Though you'd have to host those yourself. And it's a pro-only feature.

Comment: I thought that you needed LoadFromCacheOrDownload to load resources into cache before the game starts, but when I omit this code, the game resources are available and the game runs fine. Is there something I'm missing, or can I assume this to be my solution?

*I tried deleting the obb and making the app download it again, clearing cache and force quitting, downloading the beta version directly from the play store, everything!! It all seems to be working fine